# What does "We updated your name for your Form I-140" mean?

Tags: usa

While waiting for their I-140 to be approved, applicants might see the following status:

> We updated your name for your Form I-140, Immigrant Petition for Alien Worker

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in one case, it means the I-140 application is about to be approved. The very next day the USCIS application status changed to:

> Case Was Approved